# Adding Dates for Each Day of Stay

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say we have a small inn. People make reservations online. I receive a reservation number, the date they will arrive and the length of the stay. I would like not just the number of days of their stay, but the actual calendar dates as well. For example, if my source table looks like this:

```
1000|5|6/5/2021
1001|3|6/7/2021
```

Then I would expect the output to be:

```
1000|6/5/2021
1000|6/6/2021
1000|6/7/2021
1000|6/8/2021
1000|6/9/2021
1001|6/7/2021
1001|6/8/2021
1001|6/9/2021
```

I've been using the following code to generate dates, but I am having trouble joining it back to the original data..

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE
SELECT @StartDate = '2021-11-01', @EndDate = '2021-12-01'; 
WITH ListDates(AllDates) AS
(   SELECT @StartDate AS DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,AllDates)
    FROM ListDates 
    WHERE AllDates < @EndDate)
SELECT AllDates
FROM ListDates
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close to it .
(Usually, there is a calendar table and used it , instead of the recursive query. You can search on web for an example)

I don't know if you received a text/string (for the source of your data) or it's table . In this solution , I used a table (@tv_Source)

Here is one way :

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE
DECLARE @tv_Source TABLE
    (
        id int, noDays int,startDate date
    );
INSERT INTO @tv_Source(id,noDays,startDate)
VALUES(1000,5,'6/5/2021'),
     (1001,3,'6/7/2021');

SELECT @StartDate = '2021-06-01', @EndDate = '2021-07-01'; 
WITH ListDates(AllDates) AS
(   SELECT @StartDate AS DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,AllDates)
    FROM ListDates 
    WHERE AllDates < @EndDate)

SELECT AllDates,s.id
FROM ListDates as l
 INNER JOIN @tv_Source as s
    ON l.AllDates >=s.startDate 
        AND l.AllDates< DATEADD(dAY,s.noDays,s.startDate)
ORDER BY s.id ASC,l.AllDates ASC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

output:

```
AllDates   id
2021-06-05 1000
2021-06-06 1000
2021-06-07 1000
2021-06-08 1000
2021-06-09 1000
2021-06-07 1001
2021-06-08 1001
2021-06-09 1001
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=749720ec001e94102a7e0b7c0bdbbb00)):

```
CREATE TABLE booking
(
  bk_no     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  bk_nights INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (bk_nights > 0 AND bk_nights < 100), -- 100 arbitrary
  bk_sdt    DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO booking
VALUES
(1000, 5, '2021-05-06'),
(1001, 3, '2021-05-06');
```

And create a new table to hold our booking nights:

```
CREATE TABLE booking_nights
(
  nt_no    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  bk_no    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  bk_night DATE NOT NULL,
  
  PRIMARY KEY (bk_no, bk_night)
);
```

Then run the following query - it's a [`RECURSIVE CTE`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/):

```
WITH cte (n, bkno, bknt, bkdt) AS
(
  SELECT
    1,
    bk_no, 
    bk_nights,
    bk_sdt
  FROM booking
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    n + 1,
    bkno,
    bknt,
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, bkdt)
  FROM cte
  WHERE n < bknt
        
)
INSERT INTO booking_nights
SELECT c.n, c.bkno, c.bkdt 
FROM cte c
ORDER BY c.bkno, c.bkdt;
```

and then:

```
SELECT * FROM booking_nights
ORDER BY bk_no, bk_night;
```

Result:

```
 nt_no  bk_no   bk_night
     1   1000   2021-05-06
     2   1000   2021-05-07
     3   1000   2021-05-08
     4   1000   2021-05-09
     5   1000   2021-05-10
     1   1001   2021-05-06
     2   1001   2021-05-07
     3   1001   2021-05-08
8 rows
```

A note on the `CHECK` constraint part of the table definition, i.e.:

`bk_nights INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (bk_nights > 0 AND bk_nights < 100), -- 100 arbitrary`

- with the use of this constraint in conjuction with the `n` variable in the main RCTE, the maximum number of iterations will be 100. Not having a limit on this risks going into an infinite loop in the event of some data error!
- setting `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);` is dangerous, because that brake is deactivated (dbfiddle will eventually give a `Run failed` error).

  An alternative might be to set `MAXRECURSION` to something like 100 and **not** have the constraint in the table definition, but to "drive" without brakes is **never** advisable. The maximum this can be set to is [`32,767`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5111/fix-sql-server-cte-maximum-recursion-exhausted-error/) (the highest possible value of a signed 32bit INTEGER). This is discussed in another answer of mine [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/293917/34007).

A performance analysis is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef3a6f9bd8577101ec2b5b7d73a71988).